# How can I save an entire dataframe in a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

when I try to do file.write() the output in the csv file is not complete, I have more then 3000 rows of data and all I get in the file is top and bottom 50 lines. What am I doing wrong?

PS Im fairly fresh in programming :)

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
import unicodecsv

#getting stock data from Quandl API
df = quandl.get("WIKI/GOOGL")
#defining the columns I want to use
df = df[['Adj. Open', 'Adj. High', 'Adj. Low', 'Adj. Close', 'Adj. Volume']]
#creating new column and calculating using data from previously defined columns
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Low']) / df['Adj. Close']  * 100

df = df[['Adj. Close', 'HL_PCT']]
print(df)

file = open('adjClosePCT.csv', 'w')
file.write(str(df))

file.close()
```

Comment: Try [`df.to_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pandas built-in `to_csv` should do the work:

```
df.to_csv('adjClosePCT.csv')
```